# Opencart - skip step 2

Tags: php, cakephp-1.2, opencart

I'm using OpenCart v. 1.4.9.3 and I'm trying skip step 2 ->

```
index.php?route=checkout/guest_step_2
```

Do I need to modify the controller?

p/s: this opencart just for send enquiry no need payment or comment, i try to minimize all step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's possible to skip shipping, skipping payment is another thing altogether. You're going to have to use something like Cash On Delivery for the payment type, and then set the session payment type in the guest_step_2.
Here's the code for the post for that page, so you just need to remove the post, and set the payment code (in the cash on delivery method, it's "cod")
So

```
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && !isset($this->request->post['coupon']) && $this->validate()) {
        if (isset($this->request->post['shipping_method'])) {
            $shipping = explode('.', $this->request->post['shipping_method']);

            $this->session->data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_methods'][$shipping[0]]['quote'][$shipping[1]];
        }

        $this->session->data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods'][$this->request->post['payment_method']];

        $this->session->data['comment'] = $this->request->post['comment'];

        $this->redirect(HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=checkout/guest_step_3');
    }
```

becomes

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['shipping_method'])) {
        $shipping = explode('.', $this->request->post['shipping_method']);

        $this->session->data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_methods'][$shipping[0]]['quote'][$shipping[1]];
    }

    $this->session->data['payment_method'] = $this->session->data['payment_methods']['cod'];

    $this->session->data['comment'] = ''; // Make comment empty

    $this->redirect(HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=checkout/guest_step_3');
```

You will also need to move this below this line

```
$this->session->data['payment_methods'] = $method_data;
```

note this is just a concept, I've not had a chance to test it for you but in theory it will work. You could also probably get rid of this bit of code too, although I've left it in above

```
    if (isset($this->request->post['shipping_method'])) {
        $shipping = explode('.', $this->request->post['shipping_method']);

        $this->session->data['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_methods'][$shipping[0]]['quote'][$shipping[1]];
    }
```